# Cplex Python how to avoid printing the output

Tags: python, logging, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

after setting the objective function and constraints, i use

```
prob.solve()
print prob.solution.get_objective_value()
```

actually, I just want to print the objective value, however, it displays a lot of information of cplex,

```
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 5 rows and 1 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time = -0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
0.5
```

I just want to display the last line 0.5, how to avoid printing other information by Cplex? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

cplex specifies 3 output streams: log, error, warning and results.  You can disable the output with the commands.  set_xxx_stream(None).  In your example,

```
prob.set_log_stream(None)
prob.set_error_stream(None)
prob.set_warning_stream(None)
prob.set_results_stream(None)
```

will disable all output.  You can also specify an output file, instead of None.  There are also several [parameters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX933.html) that you can set to control the verbosity of the cplex output, but this is the best way to prevent cplex from printing anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the verbosity level using the `mip.display` parameter:

```
# where c is a Cplex object
c.parameters.mip.display.set(0)
```

See [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX910.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work actually, I see the link, it is to block the message for mixed integer problems, I tried to find the one for linear programming problems, but failed. It seems cplex.setout(null) will work for C++ and Java, but no such command for python....sad about it

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 ans = prob.solution.get_objective_value()
 print ans.split('\n')[-1]
```

Since Cplex is commercial I can't test if my solution is working. 
But you get the idea: split the string, get only what you want.

Comment: Actually I am running a loop to solve an LP each iteration, I do can split the solution, but every time I need to scroll down A LOT to see the results even I split it. Thanks any way.

Comment: what do you mean you need to scroll down? where is the output going out to? to your teminal? when is it outputing?