# Cplex Java how to avoid printing the output?

Tags: java, cplex

I have an optimization model has to be run within a simulation model every time at each simulation iteration. However, it displays log, error, warning and results as output of Cplex at each iteration. How can I set it off?

I found following link for the same question in python, however I was not able to find the Java command:

[Cplex Python how to avoid printing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365775/cplex-python-how-to-avoid-printing-the-output/20381881#20381881)

I wonder if anyone can help me with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I used the following code and it works.

```
   IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
   cplex.setOut(null);
```

Comment: This is the only answer to the question. The others are not related to avoiding printing but to printing in a different way or doing extra-code to have no printing

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect CPlex's output using the `setOut(OutputStream s)` method:

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
cplex.setOut(...);
```

Comment: I had done that already. It still prints out the results! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class NullOutputStream extends OutputStream {    
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    }
}
```

and then

```
setOut(new NullOutputStream());
```